# Fine tune .NET ServicePoint for many concurrent requests

Tags: .net, architecture, windows-services, httpwebrequest, dotnet-httpclient

Disclaimer: I am trying to get a feeling of real world numbers from peoples  first hand experience. No implementation details / code is needed at this point.

We have web api that will use queues / message brokers to drop messages to and then in turn, windows services will read queues for delivering different kind of http notifications (simply: send many http requests to different urls/hosts). At peek times, those numbers might be in thousands per second.

Having on mind ServicePoint max connections limit plus ThreadPool threads, i am trying to find right measure for finetuning that sending part. So, potential questions are:

1. What numbers of concurrent http requests (most probably through HttpClient) sounds reasonable to have per one windows service?
2. What are some maximums that you use in projects without problems?
3. If there are some specific things to pay attention to in order to accomplish the high number, please specify them.

Notes:

- For the moment, i am not concerned about queue/message broker limits. that part we can assume is infinite for the sake of this discussion.
- The requests are very lightweight with mostly a few kbs of data in them so response times are expected to be very short

Comment: It depends on your server's resources (specially number of cores). I would suggest run perfmon on your server and check for the number threads in your app. Normally it's better not to have more that a 1000 threads per process, which is theoretically 1000 connections, but as I said it's not that simple and you need to monitor your server load and comply with suggested benchmarks.
Have a look into this :
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.08.pulse.aspx

Comment: Another thing that comes to my mind about your 3rd question is using async/await keywords once you are doing I/O intensive jobs, like fetching data from db, persisting data in db, calling another service, etc. This way, under the hood, .net framework releases current waiting thread to be used be the others while it's waiting for the results.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will take a look into first link you've sent. About your second comment: async is most probably not an option as async is great for long(er) running IO operations but in this case when requests are expected to be very short, an overhead of creating thread on request/response might be too much.